# shift cells right similar to excel

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe that looks like this...

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

myst="""india, 905034 , 19:44   
USA, NULL, 905094  , 19:33
Russia,   905154 ,   21:56
"""
u_cols=['country', 'index', 'current_tm', 'dummy']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

The above code will generate a table that will look like this...

```
country index   current_tm  dummy
0   india   905034  19:44   NaN
1   USA NULL    905094  19:33
2   Russia  905154  21:56   NaN
```

The index value for country "USA" is NULL. I need to delete it and shift the values on right "905094" to left. So that the final dataframe will look like this...

```
country index   current_tm
0   india   905034  19:44
1   USA 905094  19:33
2   Russia  905154  21:56
```

In Excel, I can simply right click to choose "delete..." and select shift cells left option. Is there similar functionality in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is main problem different types - in column `current_tm` are `strings`, in column `index` `float`s (because `NaN`s) and need `int`s.

So first [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `NaN`s, convert to `int` and then to `str` for same types `str`.

Then get mask by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) cols, last convert to `int` and `drop` column.

```
df['index'] = df['index'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
cols = ['index', 'current_tm', 'dummy']
idx = df['dummy'].notnull().index

df.loc[idx, cols] = df.loc[idx, cols].shift(-1, axis=1)

df = df.drop('dummy', axis=1)
df['index'] = df['index'].astype(int)
print (df)
  country   index current_tm
0   india  905034      19:44
1     USA  905094      19:33
2  Russia  905154      21:56
```